# React - OpenLayers: onClick event not fired on overlay whereas onMouseUp is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers 5.3.3 and React 16.8.6.

I'm facing an issue while trying to handle a click event on an overlay displayed over a map.

This is how I create my `Overlay`:

```
new Overlay({
  id: "overlay",
  element: this.refs.mapOverlay,
  stopEvent: true
});
```

The thing is, the `onClick` event is not fired.

But some events are:

- `onClick` not triggered
- `onMouseDown` not triggered
- `onPointerDown` not triggered
- `onMouseUp` triggered
- `onMouseEnter` triggered
- `onMouseLeave` triggered

And it triggers all events if I set `stopEvent: false` at overlay's creation, but the events are propagated to the map below, which is causing other problems.

Edit: I made a prototype to test this behavior: 
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-bash-ngysz)

You can check by clicking on the overlay, the `onClick` event is not fired if `stopEvent` is set while `onMouseUp` is.